# convergence uniformly of a sequence of functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Show that $$f_n: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}; \  n\ge1; \ f_n (x)=\frac{x \sqrt{n}}{n \sqrt{n}+x^2}$$ does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$

I have showed that $f_n(x)$ pointwise converges to $0$.

Then I find the maximum of $|f_n(x)|$ and it is for $x=n^{3/4}$ and $x=-n^{3/4}$

Hence $\sup_{\mathbb{R}}{|f_n(x)|}=f_n(n^{3/4})=\dfrac{1}{2 n^{1/4}} \rightarrow 0$

Where is the mistake?

Comment: then is wrong the text of the exercise....

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370023/how-to-prove-a-sequence-of-a-function-converges-uniformly/370071#370071).

Answer (score 1):

*This post is made community wiki in order to remove this question from the "unanswered" list*

---

If what you say is true, the text is wrong.  You have shown that the sequence of functions does indeed converge uniformly on $\mathbb R$.